# When ShutdownHook is called?

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime

I have a question about `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`.

Let say that I have two Threads started in main. Both threads are working on one collection, `List<String> commonColection`.

When I press `Ctrl+C` I want to save this collection. My question is: are threads stopped before ShutdownHooks are called, or do I need to explicitly terminate my threads and after that save my collection?

Comment: I think when virtual machine starts its shutdown sequence. It will register all the shutdown hooks.

Answer (score 1):

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start
>   all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them
>   run concurrently. When all the hooks have finished it will then run
>   all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled.
>   Finally, the virtual machine will halt.

From: [Oracle Docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

As I read this, you will have to abort your threads (*not* `Thread.abort`! Instead use some means to end them gracefully!) and save your Collection. At least you will have to make sure you are saving a proper state of the collection.

If the Threads are not "infinite" and no deamons you could just let them finish. But I would not recommend this since shutdown hooks are supposed to return quickly.

Answer (score 0):

From your `shutdownHook()` you can gracefully terminate your threads by signalling them to stop. Otherwise, if your threads are `daemon threads`, then JVM will not wait for them to finish. It will exit after calling `shutdownHook()` when you press ctrl+c. Refer this [javadoc for daemon thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) behavior.